# Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER) & ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE & ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate using Selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I've been webscraping and for a variety of webpages certification worked well. That's why I don't understand the following problem:

That's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.sportwetten.de/")
```

With following Error Code:

```
[18664:9880:0317/194904.232:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 4):

This error message...

```
[18664:9880:0317/194904.232:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate
```

...indicates most likely an expired ca public cert in the browsers cert store.

---

### Details

The error is defined in [parse_certificate.cc](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:net/cert/internal/parse_certificate.cc;l=22;drc=169c6cc102b39295a5bfe2f2a176b42b1c2fe2c4):

```
namespace net {

namespace {

DEFINE_CERT_ERROR_ID(kCertificateNotSequence,
             "Failed parsing Certificate SEQUENCE");
DEFINE_CERT_ERROR_ID(kUnconsumedDataInsideCertificateSequence,
             "Unconsumed data inside Certificate SEQUENCE");
DEFINE_CERT_ERROR_ID(kUnconsumedDataAfterCertificateSequence,
             "Unconsumed data after Certificate SEQUENCE");
DEFINE_CERT_ERROR_ID(kTbsCertificateNotSequence,
             "Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE");
.
.
}
}
```

---

### Solution

To get rid of the certificate errors you need to add the argument ***`--ignore-certificate-errors`*** through an instance of *`Options`* as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options) 
driver.get("https://www.sportwetten.de/")
```

---

### tl; dr

[Chrome Root Program Policy](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy/)

Comment: Unfortunatly exactly the same errormessage is occuring.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get around this by adding

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks